# Write UI using Angular JS and Business logic using Android native

Tags: android, angularjs, user-interface

I have read lots of stuff regarding building an android app using angular JS and Cordova with Ionic looks promising.But I am wondering if it is possible to design application UI using Angular JS and business logic using android. This may sound ridiculous but this what my client asked me.

So, is it possible to do so?

The basic idea behind this is to use same UI on IPhone and other platforms if possible.

Answer (score 0):

The main advantages of using Ionic over using native android is that you can have one set of source code and compile it both for IOS and android.

So yes if you use Ionic you can use the same UI for both IOS and Android.

In Ionic there is a folder called "platforms" in there you will find android and ios folders. Yes you can build the logic for the view in pure android as everything will be there but I highly do not recommend this as it defines the point of using Ionic. Plus every time you run "ionic build android/ios" this folder will recreated so you would have to backup the folder fist then run the build command then past it again. It will be very messy and you could easily sit with issues.